Is it possible to auto-mount Synology NAS with fstab (NFSv4.1)?
I am trying to mount my new Synology DS923+ connected to my LAN switch with static DHCP reservation. OS: Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon based on Ubuntu 24.04.
I already installed nfs-common package:
$ apt-cache policy nfs-common
nfs-common:
  Installed: 1:2.6.4-3ubuntu5
  Candidate: 1:2.6.4-3ubuntu5
  Version table:
 *** 1:2.6.4-3ubuntu5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

First attempt in fstab:
192.168.0.77:/volume3/8TB /mnt/nas nfs vers=4.1,nofail,nouser,auto,rw,async,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=NAS 0 0

The above works only after boot. After login I must execute sudo mount -av, and it mounts.
So far, I cannot figure out if it is even possible to mount automatically at boot. My laptop is not connected to WiFi, I use LAN instead.
Since I am brand new to Synology NAS, please be patient with me, comment if you need any additional info. Thank you.
Note #1: As suggested in comment, I added the bg option to that fstab line options. No change, sadly.

I changed the original line to:
192.168.0.77:/volume3/8TB /mnt/nas nfs4 proto=tcp,vers=4.1,nofail,user,auto,rw,async,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=NAS 0 0
there the only important change is from nouser to user, then I do not need to mount (issue command, enter password), I just click on NAS in Nemo file manager and it allows me to mount, which is kind of what I wanted, just differently formulated.
Hope it helps. Cheers
Screenshots:
Before mount:

After mount (just a click on NAS):

